# iText7 will not initialize

Tags: itext7, hangfire

I have hangfire (hangfire.io) which is opensource job scheduler running a job that uses iText7 to build a pdf.  When I run the job as a unit test it works.  When I run it through hangfire, it errors with some sort of dependency problem.  I'm not using any encryption, only the most basic iText7 features.

```c#
MemoryStream newSourceMS = new MemoryStream();
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(newSourceMS);
writer.SetCloseStream(false);
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer); //ERROR HERE
```

The error message is : "The type initializer for 'iText.IO.Util.EncodingUtil' threw an exception."

Stack Trace

```
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfEncryption.GenerateNewDocumentId()
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument.Open(PdfVersion newPdfVersion)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument..ctor(PdfWriter writer, DocumentProperties properties)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument..ctor(PdfWriter writer)
```

I have itext.forms.dll, itext.html2pdf.dll, itext.io.dll, itext.kernel.dll, itext.layout.dll, itext.styledxmlparser.dll, itext.svg.dll and BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll in the BIN for Hangfire.

Some other dependency is missing and I can't figure out what it is.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

#### Update

By adding System.Security.Crptography.Encoding it has gotten further.  It may be the answer.

Comment: Do you have all ItextSharp dlls on your Hangfire server part (the app hosting the server part of hangfire, which builds the pdf) ?

Comment: Yes, I have iText forms/html2pdf/io/kernel/layout/svg/styledxmlparser and bouncycastl.crypto dll's in the bin.   It's defiantly some sort of missing dependency but I can't figure out which one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe iText7 depends on Common.Logging version 3.4.1, which on turn depends on Common.Logging.Core, same version 3.4.1.